# How to achieve common configuration in AWS Lambda?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, configuration, aws-lambda

**Common DB Configuration in AWS Lambda functions**

I have 50 lambda functions which calls a Mongo DB setup in AWS EC2. Currently the ip address, port number and db name are written inside all 50 lambda functions. I need to put this configuration in a single place and all Lambda functions should be able to call it.

Please guide me what's the best way to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use AWS SDK from the lambda to pull a file from S3 which contains your configuration values in a suitable form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an excellent use-case for the [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html):

> **AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store** provides secure, hierarchical storage for configuration data management and secrets management. **You can store data such as passwords, database strings, and license codes as parameter values.** You can store values as plain text or encrypted data. You can then reference values by using the unique name that you specified when you created the parameter. Highly scalable, available, and durable, Parameter Store is backed by the AWS Cloud. Parameter Store is offered at no additional charge.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried, it was very easy to set and pull values from it.

Comment: Be aware that currently AWS does not publish service limits for API requests to SSM Parameter Store. Also note that there is no way to request an increase to these undefined limits. You will need to discover in your own load testing if you run into any throttling exceptions.